# Simple VyOs Static Routing on GNS3

Tags: routing, gns3, vyos

Sorry for the beginner question. I'm trying to simply set up static routing on this GNS3 topology. Specifically, I want Sam to be able to ping Jack. I've assigned all of the VPCS machines ip's, and have configured the interfaces for each VyOS router so it matches this topology. I think I'm messing up the static routing table. I've read the [VyOS documentation](https://docs.vyos.io/en/latest/routing/static.html) and have tried the below commands:

Router1

```
set protocols static route 10.10.10.0/24 next-hop 10.10.40.1
set protocols static route 10.10.40.0/24 next-hop 10.10.10.2
```

Router2

```
set protocols static route 10.10.40.0/24 next-hop 10.10.20.1
set protocols static route 10.10.20.0/24 next-hop 10.10.40.2
```

[image]

When I try to ping Jacks machine from Sam I get No Gateway Found.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A router know the network in which it has an interface connected, so it doesn't need a route for those.

It need a route to reach remote networks. So you must tell to:

- router-1 where are the networks 10.10.20.0/24 and 10.10.30.0/24
- router-2 where are the networks 10.10.10.0/24 and 10.10.30.0/24
- router-3 where are the networks 10.10.10.0/24 and 10.10.20.0/24

So you can remove the static route you set

**Router 1**

```
delete protocols static route 10.10.10.0/24
delete protocols static route 10.10.40.0/24 
set protocols static route 10.10.20.0/24 next-hop 10.10.40.2
set protocols static route 10.10.30.0/24 next-hop 10.10.50.2
```

**Router 2**

```
delete protocols static route 10.10.20.0/24
delete protocols static route 10.10.40.0/24 
set protocols static route 10.10.10.0/24 next-hop 10.10.40.1
set protocols static route 10.10.30.0/24 next-hop 10.10.40.1
```

**Router 3**

```
set protocols static route 10.10.10.0/24 next-hop 10.10.50.1
set protocols static route 10.10.20.0/24 next-hop 10.10.50.1
```